# WebDav mirroring with Apache/Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, webdav, mirroring

Folks,
I have an "origin" server where data is being dumped using WebDav. I need to distribute this data to edge caches as soon as the data is received on the origin. I will use either Apache or Nginx for the origin and the edge server.

What is the recommended way to do a live mirroring of my content from origin to edge? Is it possible to program WebDAV triggers into Apache/Nginx that will result in the content being propagated, or should I look at something simple like rsync?

Thanks for your insights.

-Raj

Comment: Why do you need to 'push' data to NGINX? Would it not be easier just to let NGINX pull it but set/check ETag/last-modified headers?

Comment: Hi Samarudge, thanks for your response. I am generating fast changing content that needs to be on my edge nodes before the clients get there. My data source publishes the content on one server using WebDAV and I need to rapidly mirror this content on edge nodes.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm not an expert on WebDAV (I use GIT) but in GIT you can attach events to the 'post-commit' hook that will be run on every commit. I'd suggest hooking an 'rsync' to that, but like you say in your question I'm not sure if that can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inotify and rsync is a crude but effective method for doing this. Lsyncd does the job for me, but I'm ok with a few seconds lag between my origin and edge nodes. If you're after something quicker you'll need to consider spending a lot of time/money.

Comment: lsyncd looks like the thing I need. Frankly I am surprised rsync does not already do this. Keeping remote folders in sync on an ongoing basis would appear to be a pretty common use case.